# Python Why Django won't let me load a new product?

Tags: python, django, web, web-development-server

I'm in this page:
[Filling the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtSF4.png)

The ling is https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Oranges_white_background.jpg

When I'm pressing 'save' it gives me this: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rng4G.png)

Couldn't understand the issues I tried various ways to solve it like take another picture and re-run the server.
From Mosh Hamedi tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc&t=20225s  at 05:42:20

edit: adding code.

models.py

```
from django.db import models 


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)


class Offer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New Products')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

admin.site.register(Product)
```

pyshop - urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("products/", include('products.urls'))
]
```

products - urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('new', views.new)
]
```

Comment: Well I don't even have a table that called 'auth_user__old' but I do have a table called 'auth_user', Why does it search for 'main.auth_user__old' in the first place? I added the code

Answer (score 0):

Django is not able to find the table

```
main.auth_user__old
```

observe the double underscore between user and old. Are you sure it is correct?

Also, please upload your code.

Comment: Well I don't even have a table that called 'auth_user__old' but I do have a table called 'auth_user', Why does it search for 'main.auth_user__old' in the first place?
I added the code